# Spacy tagger loss is zero while training

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I use this snippet of code to train a tagger in `spacy 2.3.0`.

```
TRAIN_DATA = posData.train_data_getter()[:80000]
if model is not None:
    nlp = spacy.load(model)  # load existing spaCy model
    print("Loaded model '%s'" % model)
else:
    nlp = spacy.blank('fa')

if "tagger" not in nlp.pipe_names:
    tagger = nlp.create_pipe("tagger")
    for tag, values in TAG_MAP.items():
        tagger.add_label(tag, values)
    nlp.add_pipe(tagger, first=True)

pipe_exceptions = ["tagger"]
other_pipes = [pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe not in pipe_exceptions]
# nlp.tokenizer = Tokenizer(nlp.vocab)
with nlp.disable_pipes(*other_pipes):  # only train parser
    optimizer = nlp.begin_training()
    for i in range(n_iter):
        random.shuffle(TRAIN_DATA)
        losses = {}
        batches = minibatch(TRAIN_DATA, size=compounding(4.0, 32.0, 1.001))
        for batch in batches:
            texts, annotations = zip(*batch)
            l = []
            for t in texts:
                l.append(normalize(t, remove_punc=True))
            texts = tuple(l)
            nlp.update(texts, annotations, sgd=optimizer, losses=losses)
        print("Losses", losses)
```

The problem is that the loss value is always zero. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, this is a bug in v2.3.0. It will be fixed in the upcoming v2.3.1. You can train a tagger with `spacy train` instead or use v2.2.4 in the meanwhile.

Comment: @aab Oh! thank you. Is it fixed in recent commits? If so, I can build the project from source.

Comment: Yes, it's fixed in `master`.

Comment: @aab Thank you very much. I think it would be nice if you post an answer to the question so I can accept it. This would be a better guide for someone who runs into this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, this is a bug in v2.3.0. It will be fixed in the upcoming v2.3.1. You can train a tagger with `spacy train` instead or use v2.2.4 in the meanwhile.

If you'd like to have this fix sooner, you can also install from source in the current `master` branch (the fix is in commit `b7107ac8`).